# Disable click event for status bar in android

Tags: android

I want to disable the click event for status bar in android.how TO DO THIS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by that you mean the notification bar then you cannot disable it. However what you can do is to make you application fullscreen and that should hide the notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this. Google didn't recommand to do this for security.